# Getting error "After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'"

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I am using Spring-Integration for my project. I am experimenting with reading of the property/constant values from xml file (instead of .properties file).My xml file in which the properties/constants are placed is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>

   <persistence>
      <dataSourceName>CS/PowerSTEPP_CSSTEPPQA</dataSourceName>
   </persistence>
  <customerservice>
   <headerNames>
   <jobName>jobDesignerJobName</jobName>
   </headerNames>
   <headerNames>
      <originalPayload>originalPayload</originalPayload>
   </headerNames>
   <headerNames>
      <originalPayloadDuplicate>originalPayload</originalPayloadDuplicate>
   </headerNames>
   <headerNames>
      <legacySystem>legacySystem</legacySystem>
   </headerNames>
   <headerNames>
      <businessArea>businessArea</businessArea>
   </headerNames>
   <routing>
      <jobChannel>headers.jobDesignerJobName+'-InputChannel'</jobChannel>
   </routing>
   <routing>
      <jobErrorChannel>headers.jobDesignerJobName+'-XsltTransformInputChannel'</jobErrorChannel>
   </routing>
   <legacySystem>
      <powerstepp>PowerSTEPP</powerstepp>
   </legacySystem>
   <PQProviderSearch>
      <storedProcedureName>PQPRVSCH</storedProcedureName>
   </PQProviderSearch>
   <PQProviderSearch>
      <ROWREQ>00001</ROWREQ>
   </PQProviderSearch>
   <PQProviderSearch>
      <DBGFLG>Y</DBGFLG>
   </PQProviderSearch>
   <PQProviderSearch>
      <SECDAT></SECDAT>
   </PQProviderSearch>
   <stylesheet>
      <PQProviderSearch>classpath:/CustomerServiceRD/spring-integration/stylesheets/PQProviderSearch.xsl</PQProviderSearch>
   </stylesheet>
   <stylesheet>
      <PQProviderSearchCount>classpath:/CustomerServiceRD/spring-integration/stylesheets/PQProviderSearchCount.xsl</PQProviderSearchCount>
   </stylesheet>
   <resultSet>
      <legacySystem>system</legacySystem>
   </resultSet>
   <resultSet>
      <rootNode>results</rootNode>
   </resultSet>
   <responseXml>
      <soapTemplate>CustomerServiceRD/JobDesigner-responseTemplate.xml</soapTemplate>
   </responseXml>
   <responseXml>
      <xmlBodyTag>//PQ</xmlBodyTag>
   </responseXml>
   <http>
      <header>
         <ressponseXml>
            <contentType>
               <value>CustomerServiceRD/JobDesigner-responseTemplate.xml</value>
            </contentType>
         </ressponseXml>
      </header>
   </http>
   <http>
      <header>
         <contentType>
            <value>CustomerServiceRD/JobDesigner-responseTemplate.xml</value>
         </contentType>
      </header>
   </http>
   <error>
      <Fault>Fault</Fault>
   </error>
   <error>
      <errorCode>1111</errorCode>
   </error>
   <headerNames>
      <hostAddress>hostAddress</hostAddress>
   </headerNames>
   <headerNames>
      <hostPort>hostPort</hostPort>
   </headerNames>
   <error>
      <Fault>faultcode</Fault>
   </error>
   <error>
      <faultstring>faultstring</faultstring>
   </error>
   <error>
      <faultactor>faultactor</faultactor>
   </error>
   <error>
      <detail>detail</detail>
   </error>
   <label>
      <externalSystem>ExternalSystem</externalSystem>
   </label>
   </customerservice>
</config>
```

Now, I am trying to read the above values in spring integration configuration files as below:

```
<beans 
    <import resource="spring-integration/Jobs/*.xml"/>

    <!-- map of namespace prefix to URI -->
    <util:map id="xmlMessageNamespace">
        <entry key="SOAP" value="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" />
    </util:map>
    <int:channel id="jobDesignerInputChannel" />
    <int:channel id="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel" />

    <bean id="msgHandler" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.PQMessageHandler" />

    <!-- TODO: Following lines are commented out as part of POC.-->
    <!--<bean id="xmlAggregator" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.XmlAggregator" />
    <bean id="httpOutboundGatewayHandler" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.HttpOutboundGatewayHandler" />
    <!--<bean id="xmlFilter" class="com.dsths.cs.awd.jobs.XmlFilter" />-->

    <int:chain input-channel="jobDesignerInputChannel" >

        <int-xml:xpath-header-enricher default-overwrite="true"  should-skip-nulls="true"  >
            <int-xml:header name="${customerservice.headerNames.legacySystem}"  xpath-expression="//LegacySystem"  evaluation-type="STRING_RESULT"  overwrite="true" />   
        </int-xml:xpath-header-enricher>        

        <!-- Some of the AWD jobs contain Business Area info under <code> tag, we should not keep that business area info in the 
        header since it is not required.This will help us in identifying AWD and Non-AWD jobs-->
        <int:header-enricher>
            <int:header name="${customerservice.headerNames.businessArea}" expression="#xpath(payload, '//businessArea/Code', 'boolean') ? null : #xpath(payload, '//businessArea')"/>
        </int:header-enricher>

        <int:router expression="${customerservice.routing.jobChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>

    <int:chain input-channel="cs-exceptionHandlingChannel">
        <!-- Service Activator to handle the errors --> 
        <int:service-activator  ref="msgHandler" method="handleError" />

        <!-- Router to routing the error messages to appropriate job channel for xsl transormation -->      
        <int:router expression="${customerservice.routing.jobErrorChannel}"/>
    </int:chain>           
</beans>
```

But, unfortunately I am getting the following exception when try to read the properties from the xml file:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#3': Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#3$child#2.handler' of type [org.springframework.integration.config.RouterFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'handlers' with key [2]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#3$child#2.handler': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'expressionString' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:120)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:353)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1360)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:103)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:1)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.loadApplicationContext(TestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContext.getApplicationContext(TestContext.java:148)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#3$child#2.handler': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'expressionString' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1118)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:270)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'expressionString' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E:(pos 1): After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'lcurly({)'
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:58)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    ... 46 more
```

Anybody have any idea where I am doing wrong?
Please let me know if my question is not clear.

Comment: Where/how are you loading this xml file?

Comment: @M.Deinum , I am using customized apache configuration framework to load the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the StackTrace your issue is here:

```
<int:router expression="${customerservice.routing.jobChannel}"/>
```

Before to use such a difficult configuration you should be sure that your `customerservice` really returns all desired options.

Would be great, if you had shown how does that object look from Java perspective, rather than XML background